# SVG Content Modified when imported as ReactComponent

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-component

Firstly, the SVG file I'm trying to import already has an `id` and `classes` for its children.

```
<svg id='bg-bars' width="189" height="670" viewBox="0 0 189 670" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <line class="bar" x1="188" x2="188" y2="500" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="177" x2="177" y2="510" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="166" x2="166" y2="520" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="155" x2="155" y2="530" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="144" x2="144" y2="540" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="133" x2="133" y2="550" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="122" x2="122" y2="560" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="111" x2="111" y2="570" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="100" x2="100" y2="580" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="89" x2="89" y2="590" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="78" x2="78" y2="600" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="67" x2="67" y2="610" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="56" x2="56" y2="620" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="45" x2="45" y2="630" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="34" x2="34" y2="640" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="23" x2="23" y2="650" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="12" x2="12" y2="660" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
    <line class="bar" x1="1" x2="1" y2="670" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2"/>
</svg>
```

Because I need to animate the SVG content and I can't use it as `src` for `img` tag, I see two options to go for-

1. `import {ReactComponent as SVG} from '...'`
2. Copying the SVG content to a separate functional Component in a separate file, and export it.

The second way works as expected, but the first one modifies the svg content like so-

```
<svg width="189" height="670" fill="none">
  <path class="bg-bars_svg__bar" stroke="#108F93" stroke-width="2" d="M188 0v500M177 0v510M166 0v520M155 
  0v530M144 0v540M133 0v550M122 0v560M111 0v570M100 0v580M89 0v590M78 0v600M67 0v610M56 0v620M45 0v630M34 
  0v640M23 0v650M12 0v660M1 0v670"></path>
</svg>
```

The thing to note is that it modifies the *****content** as well as the **classes***** for children, which means I now can't animate individual `line` elements, which is what I need to do.

Here's the [reproducible](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-sun-zd498?file=/src/App.js) example. Try to toggle each `import` for `BGBars` svg, and see what the node looks like in Debug tools.

I really have no idea what works behind the scenes to modify the SVG. If I can't change the way it works, is there a ***better way than the second method*** I mentioned to achieve the goals?

Comment: Are you talking about using the second method you mentioned in the post and it modified your SVG content? Could you put together a working example that can reproduce the problem you're facing?

Comment: @konekoya I've edited the question. Please have a look

Comment: I have worked with some SVG customization by using the second method you mentioned here. I believe it's the right way to go about it.

Comment: @konekoya This method, for some reason, doesn't feel super good to me because I've to put all animatable SVGs into separate components even though these are not re-usable. I was looking for a better possible solution.